# My Iranian passport will expire on the day of my flight from Sweden to Iran (home country). I'm travelling with Emirates, would that be a problem?

Tags: iran

I'm traveling to Iran on the same day that my passport expires. I can not find information about it on Emirates website. Can I still travel and renew my passport in Iran?

Comment: As to your first question ("Can I travel?") we'll need to know a) the itinerary between Sweden and the arrival airport in Iran, and b) if you're also a citizen of another country, the identity of that other country and whether you have a valid passport from that other country.

Comment: Are you travelling on a non-stop direct flight, or will you need to transit? Try entering the full details of your trip and travel document in Timatic, the system used by airlines https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true